# Facebook share video with thumbnail

Tags: facebook, youtube, share

I have a question..and a problem maybe..
The thing is that I have this site with some youtube videos, all the videos are loaded into the same "html-page".. and I also have this feature to share the videos to facebook.
But now I whould like to share the video with a thumbnail aswell..
And I have read about the meta-tag-thingy, but the thing I dont get is..
since I have alot of different videos on the same page.. then if I share one of the videos and then the next second i share another video, then how does it know which thumbnail to share on facebook?

Comment: Will i have to change the value of the meta-tags dynamicaly once the user presses the share button..or?

Comment: Perhaps you can use some tokens to dynamicly generate open graph meta data. For example, videos are at `site.com/videocollection1`. Sharing video 1 in the collection could be `site.com/videocollection1/1`, which only contains OGP markup for video 1 while `site.com/videocollection1/2` would contain OGP for video 2. so essentially you can look at the URL and get an argument to determine which video you want to render OGP metadata for.

Comment: yes, but whouldnt that also make the link that gets shared on facebook to link to that url aswell?
for instance if i whould press the like button and that once im at site.com and then the like button shares site.com/videocollection1/1 since we want to share the video with the dynamically generated meta-tags.. then whouldnt also the link that shows up at facebook also link the users to site.com/videocollection1/1?

Comment: Yes that is correct. But if the user clicks the link, he will still arrive at a page with all the videos. Only difference is that your server-side script would see the `1` or `2` at the end of the URL and generate the appropriate metadata tags for either video 1 or video 2.

Comment: Hmm I think I might get it now :).. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uses the [open graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) to determine which thumbnail it should use for a link. The "protocol" is essentially some special markup that facebook can read.

Failing that, it uses its own algorithm to determine which thumbnail is to be used.

In your case, if you have a lot of videos on one page, my understanding is that it will choose the video that has OGP markup. If you have OGP markup for all the videos, then it will most likely choose the first one.

An alternative would be to host each videos on its own separate page. This way, there won't be any confusion was to which thumbnail should be displayed.

You can use the Facebook debugger to see what Facebook "sees" when it scrapes your pages: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug